# Extra </html> tag on creating CSV

Tags: jsf, export-to-csv

I'm trying to develop a function in order to export CSV files using JSF. here is the code I have developed

```
StringBuilder cardReport = getCoreService().createCardReport(cardType.getId());
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) WebFlowUtils.getExternalContext().getNativeResponse();
response.setContentType("text/comma-separated-values; charset=utf8");
byte[] buffer = cardReport.toString().getBytes();
response.setContentLength(buffer.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"report.csv\"");
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
WebFlowUtils.getExternalContext().recordResponseComplete();
```

the problem is that every time the result is exported there is a redundant `</html>` tag inserted at the end of file content. Besides my content is not HTML relevant at all. and when I debug the code I see the html tag does not exist there, It will be inserted on export time. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `WebFlowUtils`?

Comment: That is just a local wrapper library in order to call some functions more easily. IT just does not have any effects on the output. I tested and commented the last line of code and nothing changed. so it is impactless

Comment: Well, either `cardReport` is wrong to begin with, or the `response` is getting corrupted. Have you checked the former? And without knowing how you're getting the response object it's hard to tell what might be wrong with it.

Comment: It would be better to write the contents of your `StringBuilder` as `String` directly in your response rather than writing its bytes.